# t.map() is not a function in vercel error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, vite, mern, vercel

My code is running successfully in local environment, but when I deployed it to VERCEL and the build completed successfully it console logs error such as .map is not a function.

1. I am passing an array named places , initially it has no value till it grabs the data from backend API
2. also the passed data is in array form

I don't know why this error occurs, if the error was with my code then it would have reflected when I run it on the local environment. the problem is only with the VERCEL deployed app.

I want to know that do I need to change my code or it is a problem with VERCEL, because it runs fine locally.

Comment: please provide some code, otherwise, nobody can help you.
how do you fetch the data from the API?
how is the data initialized?